# CSRF token mismatch when redeploy laravel project in kubernetes environment

Tags: laravel, kubernetes, csrf

Currently i got an issue when redeploy my Laravel project. I use Kubernetes environment.

In Kubernetes every reployment, the pod will be replace and ip address will be change.

While website is access and then there's new deployment. I try to call Ajax method but showing CSRF token mismatch. I suspect it happens because i access it in Kubernetes environment. Until right now i haven't use Redis to control the session.

Try to look see some thread they suggest to using load balancer with sticky session. But it will impact in increasing latency and reducing stability.

Should i just reload page when CSRF token mismatch ? or is there any better way ?

Comment: Can you check this [troubleshooting blog](https://startutorial.com/view/how-to-fix-token-mismatch-exception-in-laravel-9) which helps to resolve your issue.

Comment: Is your app a SPA ? Could you provide code to help understand and test ?